# Média por hora MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, gostaria de saber se teria como retornar somente as médias por hora de uma tabela conforme abaixo:

```
id | valor |     timestamp    |
1  | 5.4   | 2017-4-20 18:00  |
2  | 3     | 2017-4-20 18:01  |
3  | 2.8   | 2017-4-20 18:40  |
4  | 2     | 2017-4-20 19:00  |
5  | 10    | 2017-4-20 19:05  |
6  | 7     | 2017-4-20 19:20  |
7  | 1     | 2017-4-20 19:55  |
8  | 5     | 2017-4-20 20:00  |
9  | 7     | 2017-4-20 20:11  |
10 | 4     | 2017-4-20 20:50  |
11 | 6     | 2017-4-20 21:00  |
------------------------------
```

..teria algum select para retornar as médias por hora, da coluna "valor"? Estou tentando mas sem sucesso...

Comment: tem sim, tá na minha resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG( valor ) , HOUR( `timestamp` )
FROM tabela
WHERE DATE_SUB(  `timestamp` , INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
GROUP BY HOUR( `timestamp` )
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Para pegar as médias por hora de todos os dias

```
SELECT AVG( valor ) , HOUR( `timestamp` ),day( `timestamp` )
FROM tabela
WHERE DATE_SUB(  `timestamp` , INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
GROUP BY HOUR( `timestamp` ), day( `timestamp` )


id | valor |     timestamp    |
1  | 5.4   | 2017-4-20 18:00  |
2  | 3     | 2017-4-20 18:01  |
3  | 2.8   | 2017-4-20 18:40  |
4  | 2     | 2017-4-20 19:00  |
5  | 10    | 2017-4-20 19:05  |
6  | 7     | 2017-4-20 19:20  |
7  | 1     | 2017-4-20 19:55  |
8  | 5     | 2017-4-20 20:00  |
9  | 7     | 2017-4-20 20:11  |
10 | 4     | 2017-4-20 20:50  |
11 | 6     | 2017-4-20 21:00  |
12 | 4     | 2017-4-21 21:08  |
13 | 6     | 2017-4-21 21:10  |
14 | 3     | 2017-4-21 21:25  |
15 | 6     | 2017-4-21 22:15  |
16 | 4     | 2017-4-21 22:25  |
17 | 4     | 2017-4-21 22:35  |
------------------------------
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas está retornando as médias só de um dia, como faço para pegar as médias por hora de todos os dias do banco mysql?

Comment: Você é o cara! Muito obrigado! eu não iria conseguir nunca essa lógica toda, Valeu! Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função de agregação AVG:

```
SELECT timestamp, AVG(valor)
->        FROM tabela
->        GROUP BY timestamp;
```

Para saber mais detalhes sobre funções de agregação (em inglês):
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg